# Why is my Swift checkbox button coming out like this?

Tags: swift

So I'm trying to implement a Swift Storyboard checklist through a custom CheckBox class for the Ui button but when I add my button onto a view controller it comes out like this. Heres my code and the simulator. Why does it come out like this?

**How the button looks**
[image: How the button looks]

**Code**
[image: the code]

import UIKit

class CheckBox: UIButton {

```
//images
let checkedImage = UIImage(named: "checked_checkbox")
let unCheckedImage = UIImage(named: "unchecked_checkbox")

//bool propety
@IBInspectable var isChecked:Bool = false{
    didSet{
        self.updateImage()
    }
}


override func awakeFromNib() {
    self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CheckBox.buttonClicked), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
    self.updateImage()
}


func updateImage() {
    if isChecked == true{
        self.setImage(checkedImage, for: [])
    }else{
        self.setImage(unCheckedImage, for: [])
    }

}

@objc func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton) {
    if(sender == self){
        isChecked = !isChecked
    }
}
```

Comment: But you forgot the code. Note: no pictures of code: copy and code and paste it into your question as text. — Also, do not include emotive autobiographical junk ("hurry up, I need this" type of thing).

Comment: do you have a have a height constraint set for the button?

Comment: @matt, sorry I added the code and you are right no emotive junk. Kbunarjo, no I have no height contstraint set, I did try setting one but it didn't work, the button is still huge.

Comment: Well, your checkbox images are too big. Make them smaller. The button is going to adopt the size of the image.

Comment: I think another best solution is set your image smaller, you can edit the image on Figma or Adobe or anything just make the image a bit smaller into the standard icon size and that will probably fix the problem.

Comment: I made the image smaller but that completely destroys the resolution of the picture, what a shame

Answer (score 0):

Set up contentMode as .scaleAspectFit, and set up imageEdgeInserts:

```
 override func awakeFromNib() {
    self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CheckBox.buttonClicked), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
    self.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    self.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 5.0, right: 50.0)
    self.updateImage()
 }
```

Then your button should be Custom type and Default style like this:

[image]

As a result you can see:

[image]

Comment: I did that but now I can't click the button to check and uncheck the box

Comment: I have updated my answer. Make sure you have not delete the line with target - action. If all right the line is on place then make sure your checkbox button is not covered other view.